# Persistence Class in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, persistence

I am working on a JavaEE project. All/Most classes i am working on reside on the data base. There fore all must support creating, editing and deleting a database entry. 
I don't want to use any frameworks.I planed to execute the queries using the traditional prepared statements.

Currently I implemented it as follows

```
public interface Entity{
    public boolean create(Entity e);//executes a query with the objects fields
    public boolean change(Entity e);//executes a query to update fields of the entity
    public boolean delete(Entity e);//deletes the entry 
    public ArrayList<Entity> getAll();//retrives all the entries in the database
}
```

Now my question

1. I'm i doing it right?
2. If a class inherites form a class that implements this interface how should it handel the methods? Should it override or call the super and add more code to handle more fields
3. Should i create another utility class to send the queries or is it ok if i add the database actions in the same class?

Appreciate in advance!

Comment: Have a look at what a [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) is. Implementing your [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) methods directly whitin your entity class isn't a good practice. What is best, a book that creates, modifies or delete itself or a librarian that does it? ;)

Comment: You mean i should create a utility class to make the database actions? or should those methods reside on the Entity that changes them? E.g in the requirement if i have "the system shall allow the user to add a category", should i create a user class with an addCategory() method?

Comment: The first you said. Also I think that you are confused on what an entity is. Think of it as a "tangible self-contained object", like a book or a user (or a category). The manager for the category is not a user but a CategoryManager (or CategoryDAO). Is in this manager that you should implement the method to create a category. Then you can call such method from your program flow and associate it to a user, if you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should distinguish entities and DAOs. Entities are the data, DAOs interact with the DB.

For example:

```
public interface Entity<K extends Serializable> {

    K getId();

}

public interface Dao<K extends Serializable, E extends Entity<K>> {

    E create(E entity);

    E update(E entity);

    E delete(E entity);

    E get(K id);

    List<E> getAll();

}
```

Then, implementations:

```
public class User implements Entity<Integer> {

    private Integer id;

    public User(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

}

public class UserDao implements Dao<Integer, User> {

    @Override
    public User create(User entity) {
        // build query
    }

    @Override
    public User update(User entity) {
        // build query
    }

    @Override
    public User delete(User entity) {
        // build query
    }

    @Override
    public User get(Integer id) {
        // build query
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAll() {
        // build query
    }

}
```

This can be improved by having a `BaseDao` abstract class for example, since DAOs will have common code for sure.

Comment: Okey, how are the two communicating. e.g when the there is a need to create an entity?

Comment: @AmanuelNega You don't necessary need entities, they are just a convenient way to handle DB objects. It's part of the [ORM concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Answer (score 3):

You are saying, that you are working on a *Java EE* project - so why don't use the APIs provided by it? There's a simple recommendation: Use JPA for it and only don't use prepared statements for CRUD operations of Java objects and don't reinvent an `Entity` which you already have at hand, together with an `EntityManager` doing all the operations you need on it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to implement is called a [Data Access Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) interface. It is in fact a well known and good practice, but judging from your interface name you want to use the [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) methods directly whitin your [entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) and is not a good idea.

You should create an interface, say

```
public interface BookDAO{
    public Book create(Book book);
    public List<Book> read();
    public Book update(Book book);
    public Book delete(Book book);
}
```

with the CRUD methods. Then you can implement such interface depending on your database, say

```
class MySqlBookDAOImpl implements BookDAO{
        private Connection conn;
        private Connection getConnection(){
           if(conn==null)
                conn = mySqlConnectionPool.getConnection();
           return conn;
        };

        @Override
        public Book create(Book book){
           Connection conn = getConnection();
           String query = "INSERT... "
        };

        @Override
        public List<Book> read(){
           Connection conn = getConnection();
           String query = "SELECT... "
        };

        @Override
        public Book update(Book book){
           Connection conn = getConnection();
           String query = "UPDATE... "
        };

        @Override
        public Book delete(Book book){
           Connection conn = getConnection();
           String query = "DELETE... "
        };
}
```

and implement the abstract methods to communicate with the database using the correct database driver (depends also from your connection policies).

Regarding your other 2 questions:

When implementing a method from an interface you always `ovveride` it. You can't call a `super` method just because there is no `super` method. You call `super` only when you [extend and override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) the method from the parent class.

The DAO should take care of sending the queries to the database and the DAO is going to create them within its methods.

Why are you so reluctant to use a framework or built in API? There are really good ones that can spare you a lot of work (like [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API)).

Answer (score 1):

- Actually I can see you are missing a very basic operation wchich is acceessing objects:

  ```
   public boolean read(Entity e);
  ```
- You should also reconsider your class name to have a more relevant one (what this class is intended to do) since naming it as `Entity` gives the allure of a bean entity not a data access interface layer. Something like `CommonDao`:

  ```
  public interface CommonDao {
    //...
  }
  ```

  This class can be extended following your `Entity` type.
- You may also need to revise your method signatures, e.g. deleting an entity should only need its identifier.
- Update your class also to use [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) which will let you gain in reusability and make your class accept any entity type:

  ```
  public interface CommonDao<T> {
    T create(T entity);
    //...
  }
  ```

---

*I highly recommand @sp00m solution.*